# SQL Server row number generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, rank

I have a requirement for below records.

```
Status    Date 
Active    17Mar2016
Active    17Mar2016
Inactive  17Mar2016
Active    18Mar2016
Inactive  18Mar2016
Inactive  18Mar2016
Inactive  19Mar2016
```

And i have show a column with data like below.

```
Status    Date         Row
Active    17Mar2016     1
Active    17Mar2016     2
Inactive  17Mar2016     1
Active    18Mar2016     1
Inactive  18Mar2016     1
Inactive  18Mar2016     2
Inactive  19Mar2016     3
Active    19Mar2016     1
```

For every status change I need start row number from 1 and continues.

Please let me know any clue on this.

Comment: google rank or row_number

Comment: Where does the last record come from?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit challenging because you need to identify groups of adjacent values.  There is a trick for doing this involving a difference of row numbers.  The rest is just `row_number()` using the grouping:

```
select status, date,
       row_number() over (partition by status, grp order by date) as row
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by status order by date)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

t-clausen makes a very good point.  The data provided does not have a fixed answer.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The question has a partial ordering based on date.  However, this is not a stable ordering, because dates (as provided in the question) are duplicated.  The above works as well as possible given the data.  What it really needs is a unique column (or set of columns) that specify the ordering -- a time component on the date column or unique identity would be typical such columns.

Comment: Since there is no time on the dates, the order of the insert would in your answer be able to give a different result than the current. 
**(row_number() over (order by date, status)-** instead of the 4th row would fix this

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . That is a really good point.  I added an explanation in the answer.